# Planar Graph: external/unbounded face

Tags: graph-theory

**G** is a planar graph.

**E** is an arbitrary edge of G.

"There exists a planar drawing of **G** where **E** is on the unbounded face of the drawing."

Why is the above statement true? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible approach: Given a drawing, we can use inverse stereographic projection to get the drawing onto a sphere. Rotating and then projecting back allows us to make any face the unbounded one.